# How to interpret Null pointer dereference by Cppcheck?

Tags: c++, cppcheck

I have come across a code during review and when i used cpp check it states an null pointer dereference error. I am unable to figure out the reason.
Below is the code:

```
CopyMemory(NULL, dummyMatrixManager.GetConstDataPtr(), dummyMatrixManager.GetNumberOfElements() * sizeof(tFloat)); 

void CopyMemory( tFloat* pDst, const tFloat* pSrc, const tSize nBytes )
{
    // copy data if pointer to this memory is valid
    if (NULL != pDst)
    {
        memcpy(pDst, pSrc, nBytes);
    }
    else
    {
        LOG_ERROR("No Data copied because memory was not properly allocated. Destination pointer was set to NULL.");
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Strange code. Especially this condition: `(NULL != pDst)`.

Comment: @Ron: Yes..very strange

Comment: `NULL` is and has been standard C++ since its inception. Not sure why commenters are having trouble with it. @Ron What's strange about checking if `NULL` is passed in?

Comment: @hvd I am used to seeing literals/rvalues on the right hand side. That part is confusing to me.

Comment: @Ron There is a fairly popular style that prefers constants on the left side of `==` comparisons, to ensure the code will fail to compile if the programmer accidentally types `=` instead. Even though I don't use that style myself, I don't think there's anything strange about it.

Comment: @Ron is from the olden days when compilers didn't warn about `=` in if statements. Putting NULL on the left gave a compilation error.

Comment: I see, that clarifies it for me. Appreciate it. Thanks all.

Comment: Why are you checking against NULL? The idiomatic way would be `if(pDst) {...`

Answer (score 3):

`void CopyMemory( tFloat* pDst, const tFloat* pSrc, const tSize nBytes )` has 2 parameters passed as pointers, `pDst` and `pSrc`. However, before calling `memcpy(pDst, pSrc, nBytes)`, just `pDst` is checked against `NULL`, not `pSrc` too.

Comment: It does not help. Cppcheck still shows error at the CopyMemory function call line.

Answer (score 1):

I am a Cppcheck developer. The warning might be wrong, but it's hard to say when I can't reproduce.

I hope you are using a recent version of Cppcheck (1.84 is latest).

The default text output does not say so much why Cppcheck thinks there is a NULL pointer. Could you try the `--template=gcc`? You should be able to see how Cppcheck reached the conclusion that there is a null pointer then.

Best regards,
Daniel Marjamäki

Comment: I reproduced with 1.84 even with template=gcc. See my answer above (below now) for the code.